# SwiftUI NavigationBar not disappearing while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui, combine

I want to hide my `NavigationBar` while scrolling, actually It must hide automatically but when I tried with multiple views It doesn't work. Also, It works when I remove custom views and capsulate `List` with `NavigationView`. But I need `SearchBar` and `StatusView` view. Is there any suggestion?

By the way, I run it on the device, I use canvas here for demonstration purposes.

Thank you.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                SearchBar(searchText: $viewModel.searchText)
                StatusView(status: $viewModel.status)
                Divider()
                List(0...viewModel.characters.results.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    if index == self.viewModel.characters.results.count {
                        LastCell(vm: self.viewModel)
                    } else {
                        ZStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(detail: self.viewModel.characters.results[index])) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }.hidden()
                            CharacterCell(character: self.viewModel.characters.results[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Characters", displayMode: .large)
            }

        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.getCharacters()
        }
    }
```

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just idea, scratchy... try to put your custom views inside `List` as below (I know it will work, but I'm not sure if autohiding will work)

```
NavigationView {
  List {
      SearchBar(searchText: $viewModel.searchText)
      StatusView(status: $viewModel.status)
      Divider()

      ForEach (0...viewModel.characters.results.count, id: \.self) { index in
      ...
```

Comment: This works, but it would be nice if the SearchBar and the StatusView would stay at the bottom and not disappear while scrolling, like the official Address Book app from Apple. How could that be achieved?

Comment: Ok, I've just found out myself, please see the seperate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Asperi's solution, I wanted to have the SearchBar and StatusView always visible, i.e. it should stop scrolling after the title has disappeard. You can achieve this with a section header like shown below (just a rough sketch):

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        Section(header: {
            VStack {
                SearchBar...
                StatusView....
            }
        }) {
            ForEach...
        }
    }
}
```